# Changing a Window's message loop thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, message-loop

Recently I tried putting a window's message loop in its own thread, and I wondered why it never received any messages, but I have learned that Windows posts messages to the thread that created the window. How do you create a window in one thread and cause another thread to receive that window's messages? I have seen the PostThreadMessage function but I believe that it also requires for the thread that created the window to listen for messages, which is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid, so that function is not what I need.

This seems like it would be a common question and I have spent quite a bit of time Googling for an answer, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 12):

> How do you create a window in one
>   thread and cause another thread to
>   receive that window's messages?

Simple answer ... you don't.  Create the window on the thread you want to process its messages.  If this is not possible then you need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Is there a complex answer, or is the simple answer the only one?

Comment: @Epro: Thats the only answer I'm afraid.

Comment: Is this approach you suggested the one that is used by programs which have many windows open at once?

Comment: Yes.  In fact it is perfectly normal, and extremely common, to have a many windowed application running on a single thread ...

Comment: @Goz:  it might not be the *only* answer, but it almost certainly the only answer that makes sense for anything but a research project.  See my answer.

Comment: @John:  TBF I did consider your method 2 (Method 1 I hadn't ever thought of) but I consider it a bit of a non-solution ... its far easier to just post a create message to another thread so the window gets created in that thread insted, IMO :)

Answer (score 6):

The Windows message pump is really just a `while` loop that picks messages off a queue using `PeekMessage()` and call's your windows WndProc function.  There's a little more to it than that, but that's the basic operation.

As such, whatever thread the `while` loop runs in is the one and only thread your windows can "run" in.  This is how every windows application I have ever seen is built.

However I have thought in the past that given a good deal of effort, it should be possible to construct a windows app with windows in multiple threads.  I don't have any code to show you because it's been a long time since I thought about this, but there were two approaches I considered:

1. Keep one message pump in the main thread.  But modify the message pump code so that in the `while` it dispatches messages to worker threads using `QueueUserAPC` based on the thread that particular `HWND` is running in.  A lookup map would be required for this, which can be computationally expensive.
2. Create a whole new message pump in a worker thread.  You would have to write all the `while` code, but this is simple enough, and [Petzold's classic book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)  will give you all the tools you need to do this.

Note that this approach makes no sense from an architectural point of view for any application I can think of.  You simply don't need windows to run in multiple threads if you construct your app reasonably.  Window handling happens in one thread, operations happen in another (or many).  However, I have though this was an interesting research area, and that's what led me down this path.  Long story short, I'm virtually certain you don't need to do this and shouldn't do this -- but this might be how you would do it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible. Each window *belongs* to the thread that created it, and that ownership cannot be transferred.

It's not a matter of putting your message pump in another thread. Each thread has its own message queue. When you send or post a message to a window, the OS checks which thread owns that window and directs the message to that thread's message queue. Threads cannot read any message queue but their own, so you cannot have a thread process the messages of another thread's windows.

You could re-dispatch messages to another thread, as in [the first idea in John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347404/changing-a-windows-message-loop-thread/4347549#4347549), but as a general-purpose message handler, that will become more complicated than it's worth. Many messages are meant to modify the state of the window, but you can't modify the state except from the window's own thread. Some messages are sent with the intention of getting a meaningful return value, but you can't know what to return until the message has been processed, so you'd have to block, waiting for the worker thread to process the message.

You'd be better off identifying the small set of messages that really can be off-loaded to a worker thread and handling them specially. Once you do that, you won't really have a window whose messages are handled in a different thread; you'll just have an ordinary worker thread, and it will be much less confusing to reason about.

If there are messages being *sent* to your window that require a lot of time to process, but the sender either doesn't need to know the result or you know the result before you finish the processing, then you can give an *early response* by calling [`ReplyMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644948.aspx). That lets the sending thread continue running while your window's thread does additional work.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956%28VS.85%29.aspx) works for you - it lets you handle messages from other threads.

This is really not that common of a question, because you almost always handle a windows' message in the thread where it was created. See Goz' answer; I agree.

Note that you will gain nothing from putting message processing in another thread. Don't break up GUI tasks into multiple threads, break up processing / background tasks into threads.

Comment: That's not what ATI does.  It merely allows two threads to share input state.  Like focus and keyboard state.

Comment: Using two separate threads for message processing could allow for greater parallelism in a U.I.  For example, two different windows could post messages to each other's thread message queues and both could continue processing normally, whereas with a single thread, the posting and processing of messages would be serialized.  Processing of messages in two separate threads would occur in parallel, whereas with a single thread, messages would have to be processed serially.

Answer (score -1):

see this:

msdn:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx

The thread to which the message is posted must have created a message queue, or else the 
call to PostThreadMessage fails. Use the following method to handle this situation.

1.Create an event object, then create the thread.

2.Use the WaitForSingleObject function to wait for the event to be set to the signaled state before calling PostThreadMessage.

3.In the thread to which the message will be posted, call PeekMessage as shown here to    force the system to create the message queue.

```
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE)
```

4.Set the event, to indicate that the thread is ready to receive posted messages.

Comment: This does not retrieve messages from the original window.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't really answer the original question on how to move the entire processing to another thread. As such, I recomend deleting this answer.