# Window procedure and CreateWindowEx function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Does the Window Procedure specified as `lpfnWndProc` by window class during registration runs in a separate thread ?

Comment: Your first question is _awfully broad_.  What does "really works" mean, really?  I suggest you [edit] this question to only ask one, specific question.

Comment: Reference this (or similar) with a specific question - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program  Include the code for the question in the question.

Comment: @DrewDormann. I've removed the very "general/broad" part of my question. I'd really like to know if the `window procedure` runs in the main or separate thread...

Comment: _"...runs in a separate thread ?"_ - No - it runs on the same thread as you called `CreateWindowEx` .  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347404/changing-a-windows-message-loop-thread

Comment: @RichardCritten, Ok. thx:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important concept in windows called the `message loop`.

It is usually inside the main function (aka: WinMain) and can be characterized in the following manner:

```
while (true) {
  // blocks until there's a new message to process
  GetMessage()
  TranslateMessage()
  // ends up calling the propper WndProc callback
  DispatchMessage()
}
```

**Update:** When you create a window, the thread on which the window is created *owns* the windows (and the its message queue). Therefor, it must provide the message loop process. This is usually done in the application's main thread but, as other user stated, it can also be done in a separate thread.

The function `DispatchMessage` takes care of executing the `WindowProc` procedure of the window targeted by the message (as specified by the message's `hwnd` parameter).

So, when you create a window, the `lpfnWndProc` parameter specifies where you want to be notified for events (mouse clicks, keyboard presses, etc). And it is always called in the same thread (the application's main thread or the one which owns the window).

**A word of advice:** If you need to perform a potentially long operation as the result of an event, you must create a new thread (aka background worker) for the task, and perform some kind of IPC to notify the main thread when the function is finished.

You can find instructions about how to write a windows procedure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/writing-the-window-procedure). Also, there is some info about the main loop in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: `DispatchMessage` calls the window procedure for *posted* messages.  *Sent* messages call the window procedure either from inside `SendMessage` (if called from the thread that owns the window) or from inside `GetMessage()` (and it doesn't return to the message loop)

Comment: This is missing just about every important detail, and makes awfully misleading statements. There is no such thing as a *"main thread"*. There's a *"primary thread"*, but that isn't special in any way. It's the call to `CreateWindow` that establishes a window's thread affinity and defines the thread on which the window procedure is to be called. Frankly, this reads like you are regurgitating what you were taught without having digested the lessons. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Window Procedure specified as `lpfnWndProc` by window class during registration runs in a separate thread ?

No, it is called (as a callback) when events (aka messages) are dispatched by your message loop.  In this way - the so-called 'event-driven' model - your program is able to react to user input as and when it happens without having to deal with any multi-threading or re-entrancy issues.

You might have more than one thread, but if it has windows associated with it (i.e. `CreateWindowEx` was called by that thread) then it would need to have its own message loop.

Comment: The window procedure **is** re-entrant. That's the whole reason why the STA wasn't good enough and we had to invent the [ASTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210224-00/?p=104901).